# Can monsters drop their action figures inside ancient vaults?

Tags: starbound

The recent addition of the ancient vaults gave some more to do in the post-game. They are filled to the brim with the unique monsters and have plenty of rewards.

**I was wondering if the unique monsters can still drop their respective action figures while inside the ancient vault**. I only question this because, so far, I haven't gotten a single action figure drop (though the chance is only 1/1000) and also, ancient vaults have slightly modified rules in the first place (like not dropping items when you die in survival).

I'm hoping they still do because it is a great place to farm these monsters but, I don't want to kill every monster in the vault if they only drop essence and the special crafting materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://starbounder.org/Ancient_Vault) is the first link google gave me when I searched for `ancient vault`.

It says following:

> Action figure drop chance from monsters in Ancient Vaults (0.12%) is 20-50% higher than that from monsters outside of Ancient Vaults (0.08% for no-meat monsters and non-hunting kills of meat-dropping monsters, 0.1% for hunting kills of meat-dropping monsters).

Answer (score 1):

After going through a considerable number of dungeons I finally got a monster to drop an action figure.

So yes, they can drop their action figures while inside an ancient vault.